# JPA OneToOne not Updating Foreign Key

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, data-annotations, spring-annotations

I have a class in Java that have an @Id Column. This is a Primary key of CAR:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class CarDomain {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "car")
    private EngineDomain engine;
    
}
```

And in Engine class i have a Primary Key (the Id of the engine) and i a Foreign Key car_id to reference the ID of CAR thats the engine belongs:

```
@Entity
public class EngineDomain {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CarDomain car;
    
}
```

In my PostgresDB the Engine table is loading the car_id column with ALL values NULL.

Inserting the engine_id ForeignKey in the table CAR, all values loads correctly. The engine_id that car belongs. But when i have @JoinColumn in the Engine table to have the car_id, values comes NULL.

Answer (score 1):

In your one-to-one relationship, `Engine` entity is the owner of the relationship because the `engine` table has the `car_id` property, and `car` table doesn't have a `engine_id` property. Therefore, `Engine` entity is the owner of the relationship.

You have to put `@JoinColumn` annotation in the `Car` property of the `Engine` class and the `@OneToOne` annotation with the property `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`. The `Car` entity is the other side of the relationship but it's not the owner of it, therefore you have to put the `@OneToOne` annotation with the `mappedBy = "car"` property.

If when you save an entity you also want the other side to be saved too, you must persist the `Engine` object because is the owner:

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
Car car = new Car();

engine.setCar(car);

entityManager.persist(engine);
```

If you persist the `car` object instead of the `engine`, the `engine` object is not persisted:

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
Car car = new Car();

car.setEngine(engine);

entityManager.persist(car);
```

If you want to invert this behavior, change the `car` table adding to it the `engine_id` column and a foreign key to the `engine` table. Remove the `car_id` column from the `engine` table. You must also remap the entities, mapping the `Engine` property of `Car` with the `@JoinColumn` and removing it from the `Engine` entity, so the `Car` entity will be the owner of the relationship. In this way, you can save the `Car` entity and also the `Engine` entity will be saved.

Comment: Hello JMSilla. Sorry for delay. I made the appropriate corrections on Friday based on what you’ve instructed. The problem was in the order I was persisting the object. It worked out! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Replicating your sample [as follows](https://github.com/fladdimir/so-jpa/blob/one-to-one-cascade/src/test/java/org/demo/onetoonecascade/CarEngineTest.java), I did not encounter any issues when saving and retrieving a newly created car with an associated newly created engine (even without explicitly saving the engine, as @JMSilla suggested).

Even though the `engine` is the owning side of the relation, the `persist` operation during the `save` of the (non-owning) `car` is cascaded to the (owning) `engine` (due to `CascadeType.ALL`).

However, this only works, when the association is properly synchronized (mutual references are set):

```
    car.setEngine(engine); // <-- save(car) will cascade persist to engine
    engine.setCar(car); // <-- saving the engine will also persist the foreign key of the associated car

    repository.save(car); // both entities and their association are persisted
```

Comment: Hello, Fladdimir. It worked out! Thank you very much! Have a good week.

Comment: You are welcome! feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" or upvote it in case it helped solving the issue

Comment: Hi, i have same same problem even after cascade ALL, since i have multiple one-to-one with inverse relation. Please help